# Better way to implement dynamic subdomain - Flask

Tags: python, flask, subdomain

I'm developing a Flask application and I would like to know if exist any other way to improve the method I implemented the subdomain.

Current method:

Structure:

```
arquivos/
|
├── gerenciador/
|   └ cadastro/
|     ├── templates/
|     |
|     ├── __init__.py
|     └── cadastro.py
|
├── __init__.py
└── views.py
```

file __ init __.py (arquivos/)

```
from flask import *

from .gerenciador.cadastro.cadastro import cadastro

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(cadastro, url_prefix='/cadastro', subdomain='<subdomain>')

import arquivos.views
```

file views.py (arquivos/)

```
from flask import *
from . import app

@app.route("/", subdomain="<subdomain>")
def username_index(subdomain):
     pass
```

file __ init __.py (gerenciador/cadastro/)

```
from flask import *

cadastro = Blueprint('cadastro', __name__, template_folder='templates')

from . import cadastro
```

file cadastro.py (gerenciador/cadastro/)

```
from flask import *
from . import cadastro

@cadastro.route('/teste', subdomain='<subdomain>')
def cadastro_inicio(subdomain):
    return 'cadastro ' + str(subdomain) + ', hello!'
```

This method is working, but every time I need to create a new route in gerenciador/cadastro/cadastro.py I need to repeat the "subdomain='< subdomain >'" and pass the "subdomain" to the function. Is possible to make it dynamic (without use subdomain in this file)?

Obs: If subdomain is supressed I get this error:

```
typeError: name_of_the_function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subdomain'
```

Comment: maybe for every domain run separated flask.

Comment: But every subdomain running in separated flask implies restart the server, this can't be possible due to number of clients.